# Excel Formula to count specific text on a range if another range contains specific text

Tags: excel, formula

so i am working on a financial spreadsheet, and i need to be able to count if an item has been paid, to begin, i have a column that has the items, this column is using data validation, so you can select an item from a drop down list, the column next to it, is also using data validation, so you can select the "Status" of that item, which could be "paid, waiting, denied", i'd like to be able to count how many of a specific item has been paid, waiting, or denied,but it also needs to check for a date range, so far i created a formula to count the items that have been sold on a specific date range by using "COUNTIFS", but i dont seem to find a way to count the items, that have been paid, on a date range, like so:

```
    A         B             C                            D (PAID ITEMS) 
  ITEM     STATUS     DATE OF PAYMENT             January - APPLES=  1
                                                  February - ORANGES= 1
 APPLES    PAID          1-Jan-17
 BANANAS  WAITING
 ORANGES   PAID          1-Feb-17
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: In column `D` how it comes `January - APPLES= 2`? It should be `1` instead `2`.

Comment: `COUNTIFS` will also find the count of items which paid in certain period (between two date). Put some more data.

Comment: yes, my bad! :-s

Answer (score 0):

Let me brief you to the formula that you are looking for,

It should be like:

```
= COUNTIFS(<cell range for status>, "PAID", <cell range for date> ,">="&DATE(yyyy,mm,dd), <cell range for status> ,"<="&DATE(yyyy,mm,dd))
```

Just  fill in the values accordingly.

Remember COUNTIFS allows you to incorporate multiple conditions via "AND" logic.

Comment: I am having trouble implementing the date, i already have a formula that does the same but only checks for 1 text string, and then checks the date ranges, basically i need this to do the same, but to find 2 different text on 2 different ranges, i believe the formula provided would work, but would only considers the status range, and not the item as well

Comment: @Wolf It would be great if you could elaborate more using an example (show the exact expected output you want).

Comment: i actually did, on my first post, i show under the coded section block, how i want the output to be, considering text from column A and B, if it finds the specified text for both columns, it will count the instances that text appears on that column, so if there are 10 "APPLES" on column A, and they all have a status of "PAID" on column B, AND ALSO CONSIDER THE DATE ON COLUMN C IF IT FITS WITHIN A RANGE, ex: "January" it will count and show on column "D",  "January APPLES sold = x amount"

Answer (score 0):

So my range was somewhat wrong, it was past the "FORMATTED CELLS" so it was lets say range "A1:A10" for the formatted cells, these cells are merged down the column, the formula was "A10:A16", so past A10, the cells are not merged, for some reason if the formula is past the formatted and merged cells, it won't calculate the formula properly, so what i learned i guess, was to check the specified range considers that all the cells on that range have the same formatting and size "merged or unmerged" cells

Comment: if anyone is interested on the syntax, is as follows, i gave precedence to the date range:  
=COUNTIFS(C1:C10,">="&G1,C1:C10","<="&H1,B1:B10,"PAID",A1:A10"APPLES")